# Retrieving file data from component function

Tags: angular, typescript

When an user drags and drop a file, I need to retrieve it from the `drop` event. How can I do this ?

**HTML file**

```
<div (drop)="drop($event)" >
drop file here

</div>
```

**TS file**

```
drop (event) {
 console.log(event.target.files.length);
 // I need to retrieve the file here
}
```

The console.log prints an error as the files isn't found. How can I retrieve the file from `drop(event)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like that:

```
<div (drop)="onDrop($event)" (dragover)="onDragOver($event)" >



  onDragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  onDrop(event): void {

    event.preventDefault();

    const file = event.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsFile();
    console.log(file);
  }
```

Comment: It says can't read property '0' of undefined. Am I missing something ?

Comment: here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop